# Using has many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

Using has_many => through association.

Here is what i have.

:planning model

```
has_many :acttypes
has_many :actcategories
has_many :acts, :through => :actcategories
```

:acts model

```
belongs_to :acttype
has_many :actcategories
has_many :plannings, :through => :actcategories
```

:actcategories  model

```
named_scope :theacts, lambda { |my_id|
{:conditions => ['planning_id = ?', my_id] }} 
belongs_to :act
belongs_to :planning
```

:acttype model

```
has_many :acts
```

My Problem Starts here.  I need to show all **Acts** by each **Act Type** from **Plannings** that is part of the **actcategories association**
Right now i am getting all the acts and missing the **actcategories association**.

Planning Controller

```
def show
@planning = Planning.find(params[:id])
@acttypes = Acttype.find(:all, :include => :acts)
@acts = Actcategory.theacts(@planning)
end
```

Planning Show View

```
<% @acttypes.each do |acttype|%>
<%= acttype.name %>

<% @acts.each do |acts| %>
<li><%= link_to acts.act.name, myacts_path(acts.act, :planning => @planning.id) %></li>
<% end %>
<% end -%>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key thing you're missing is that finders and named scopes only return the Class that they're called on.

```
@acts = Actcategory.theacts(@planning)
```

@acts is all the Actcategories where `actcategories.planning_id = @planning.id`. They don't necessarily have the required act type.

Really, what I think you're looking for is this named scope:

```
class Act < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :with_planning, lambda do |planning_id|
   { :joins => :actcategories, 
    :conditions => {:actcategories => {:planning_id => planning_id}}
   }
  ...
end
```

Which limits acts to those associated with the given planning. This can be called on an association to limit the linked acts to those associated with a specific planning.

Example: @acts contains acts of acttype, x, that are associated with planning, y.

```
@acts = Acttype.find(x).acts.with_planning(y)
```

With this named scope this code should accomplish what you were aiming for.

controller:

```
def show
  @planning = Planning.find(params[:id])
  @acttypes = Acttype.find(:all, :include => :acts)
end
```

view:

```
<% @acttypes.each do |acttype| %>
<h2> <%= acttype.name %><h2>
  <% acttype.acts.with_planning(@planning) do |act| %>
    This act belongs to acttype <%= acttype.name%> and 
     is associated to <%=@planning.name%> through 
     actcatgetories: <%=act.name%>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```